# $f \in C(\mathbb R)$ such that $f\Big(x+\dfrac 1n \Big) > f\Big(x-\dfrac 1n \Big) , \forall x \in \mathbb R , n \in \mathbb N$ ; is $f$ increasing?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Let $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ be a continuous function such that $f\Big(x+\dfrac 1n \Big) > f\Big(x-\dfrac 1n \Big) , \forall x \in \mathbb R , n \in \mathbb N$ , then is it true that $f$ is increasing ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put $x = y+\frac 1 n$ for arbitrary $y$; so $f(y) < f(y + \frac 2 n)$ for all $y\in \mathbb R$ and $n \in \mathbb N^*$. Put $n=2k$, this means $f(y) < f(y+\frac 1 k)$ for all $y, k$. Now: repeating, $f(y) < f(y+\frac p k)$ for all positive integers $p$. Then for any $z>y$ choose a sequence of positive rational numbers that converges to $z-y$; this will show $f(y) <= f(z)$, and in fact the inequality is strict because $f(y)$ is already $<f(y+\frac 1 n)$ for some $n > \frac 1 {z-y}$, and you can apply the non-strict inequality to $y+\frac 1 n$ and $z$.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. First to smooth out some irrelevant details: The given inequality is the same as $$f(x+2/n)>f(x)\quad(x\in\Bbb R),$$which implies $$f(x+1/n)>f(x),$$and hence $$f(x+r)>f(x)\quad(r>0,r\in\Bbb Q).$$

Now say $a<b$. Choose a sequence of rationals $r_n\in(0,b-a)$ such that $r_n$ increases to $ b-a$. Since $f$ is continuous we have $$f(a)<f(a+r_1)\le f(a+r_n)\to f(b),$$so $$f(b)\ge f(a+r_1)>f(a).$$

You might note that it's false if $f$ is not continuous, for example $$f(x)=\begin{cases}
x,&(x\in\Bbb Q),
\\x+1,&(x\notin\Bbb Q).
\end{cases}$$

Comment: I think I beat you to this solution... by two minutes... I believe the protocol was, when that happens, you refrain from posting your solution? Perhaps I got the protocol wrong.

Comment: About the example, I think $f$ does not satisfy the condition: what we have is $f(x+r)=f(x),$ not $f(x+r)>f(x).$

Comment: @mathguy For heaven's sake. Two minutes. Your answer appeared while I was typing. You say there's a "protocol" that says I'm continually supposed to check for new answers while I'm typing?

Comment: @awllower Look again. $f(x+r)=f(x)+r$.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich - err.. on my screen, whenever a new answer is posted for the problem I am working on, I see a banner alerting me to that. Do you not get that? IF that does happen, then yes, I believe the protocol is you look to see if someone else hasn't already posted exactly the same answer. Happens to me all the time!

Comment: @mathguy : sorry but for such a basic question, I'd say the protocol is : the best explained answer wins

Comment: @user1952009 Completely agreed. In this case, though, the solution is identical (except the counterexample, which was added after I posted my comment).

Comment: @mathguy (For heaven's sake)${}^2$. Where can I read about this protocol?

Comment: @mathguy "Which was added after I posted my comment". Again, your comment appeared while I was typing. What is the big deal?

Comment: Well, you clearly disagree, so what's the point. You are free to do as you please; I thought you weren't aware of my solution being posted first, but apparently that's not the issue. It's a free forum, do as you please.

Comment: @mathguy You should look around. What happens to me all the time, well some of the time, is people post solutions the same as mine hours later...

Comment: @mathguy You "thought" I wasn't aware of that? I _said_ I wasn't aware of that. Seriously: _Where_ can I read about this protocol?

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Sorry, I mistook that function as the characteristic function of $\mathbb Q.$ Sorry for that.

Comment: I generally delete my answer if I see  an answer, bascially the same as mine, that was posted before mine. It doesn't matter to me if was posted only 20 seconds before mine. Now sometimes in these cases I will leave that answer if I think it adds something of value. These are subjective judgments, and can result in wailing and gnashing of teeth. In this problem I think the best answer would have been to give the hint to show the hypotheses imply $f(x+r) > f(x)$ for all rational $r.$ Continued below ...

Comment: But that is just my opinion. And if I had given that hint and you guys had then posted your solutions, there would be a small gnash or two, but by now I'm used to it. Many of my hints have been wiped out in such situations. Other funny things happen on MSE. Take a nice little limit problem. Members of MSE tend to be good at limits, even tough ones, and it's like wasps on watermelon on such questions. There is such a rush to post that the first solution posted is often not to the best one. I could mention other complaints, but really, I am glad MSE is here.

Comment: @mathguy See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1798311/k-compact-metric-space-is-there-a-finite-set-of-continuous-functions-that-sep/1798328#1798328 In case you don't get there soon enough, note that Israel's answer appeared a minute after mine. Note the lack of comment from me about that.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich   What is this lack of comment on your part supposed to signify? You already said you were ignorant of the "protocol" in question.

Comment: @zhw. My point was just that it happens that people post duplicate answers while people are typing, and the duplicated people don't always make a big deal of it.

Comment: FWIW a [meta thread on "identical" answers](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/8191/about-posting-identical-answers-to-a-question). Also the dynamic notices do not always work; it depends on the internet connection and the current load of the system etc.